# Issue with comparing dates in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sysdate

I have a table with the following columns

effective_start_date
effective_end_date
person_id

This is on Oracle DB.
I am writing a query to get me the person active for the current sysdate, using the following query.

```
select startDate, endDate, sysdate
from dateTable
where sysdate between startDate and endDate;
```

The issue is that this where clause never seems to get applied. The result contains rows that dont satisfy this condition. Any suggestions on what i might be missing.

Comment: What db? They are of the same type?

Comment: Could you give a few sample values for the three fields

Comment: All three columns are of `Date` type..? Make sure that u have them equal..

Comment: Query is perfect and should work. Kindly provides some results to show the issue

Comment: Yes, all columns are of Date type.

Comment: People have been using BETWEEN with dates (including SYSDATE) for literally decades. If it's not working the way you expect it's because there is a problem with your data. Remember that dates in Oracle always contain a time element.

Comment: Can you verify that the date values in the table have sensible years, in the expected century, by selecting `to_char(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` etc?

Comment: @AlexPoole, ah thanks. That helped verify the year. Dates were displayed as 12-DEC-31, where 'year' 12 was not 2012, but 4712, which obv is greater that sysdate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine, and as APC suggests this is a common pattern. Which means you have a data problem. Displaying the full year will show why the unexpected records are matching, and any 'bad' dates - e.g. using unexpected centuries, which is not an unusual problem when dates are manipulated using a `YY` format mask:

```
select to_char(startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as startDate,
    to_char(endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as endDate, sysdate
from dateTable
where sysdate between startDate and endDate;
```

In the comments you've already noted that this showed dates from `4712`, which showed as just `12` using your `YY-MON-DD` date format mask. I haven't seen exactly that, it's more common to see `0012` or `1912`, but a record with `endDate` in `4712` certainly ends after `sysdate`. It's probably worth verify all of the dates in the table, not just those that were flagged by that `where` clause.